# Gensim 4.2.0 downloader function is missing

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I'm using the Gensim package. However, when I want to load the word2vec model, the `gensim.downloader` function seems not to exist.

```
w2v = gensim.downloader.load('word2vec-google-news-300')
```

Got error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'gensim' has no attribute 'downloader'
```

I checked the directory of gensim using dir() method and here's what I got:

```
['__builtins__','__cached__','__doc__','__file__','__loader__','__name__','__package__','__path__','__spec__','__version__','_matutils','corpora','interfaces','logger','logging','matutils','models','parsing','similarities','topic_coherence','utils']
```

Seems like the downloader method is not in the directory. I wonder if there's another way to download a specific pretrained model with gensim library and also what's wrong with the gensim downloader.

My gensim version is 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're following some example code, you should copy its imports & code exactly. I don't think you'll find any docs/examples suggesting to use the `gensim.downloader` module the way you've attempted.

More generally: I recommend against using `gensim.downloader`. It hides the actual sources, local paths, & return types of the data it retrieves, and also runs new code, from the net, that's not part of the Gensim project source-control nor part of versioned Gensim releases. (It's a sketchy software-engineering practice.)

Instead, download the `GoogleNews` dataset directly from some host, saving the exact original file(s) to a specific place of your choosing. Examine the downloads to understand their filenames/formats (decompressing if necessary).

Then use other Gensim methods – such as `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format()` – to load from a specific known local file path, with a returned object of a specific documented type.

Your code (and your own understanding) will be more clear, robust, & secure.

Comment: Thank you @gojomo for your reply. Do you mean that I should train the word2vec model myself instead of loading the pretrained ones?

Comment: Often running your own training makes sense, too! But here, I'm just suggesting that if you want to use the famouse (albeit now a decade-old) `GoogleNews` vectors, which Google Inc researchers released around 2012 alongside the 1st word2vec papers, you download it yourself using something like a web browser or command-line tool like `wget` or `curl`, from some trustworthy place. For example, Google's own download link is available from the page: https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/